# TL-WR740N router or switch?

Tags: router, switch, tp-link

In [this description page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DZb8cblm7sIJ:www.tp-link.com/products/productDetails.asp%3Fpmodel%3DTL-WR740N+tl-wr740n+router+switch&cd=1&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br), it says that:

> The TL-WR740N is a combined
>   wired/wireless network connection
>   device integrated with
>   internet-sharing router and 4-port
>   switch.

So, it's a router for wireless, and with 4 ports switch? Can a single device be both like this?

Comment: The faq says I can ask about "Networks" and "Desktop PCs that you maintain in the workplace". So why this was close as off topic?

Comment: Also, you that closed this question may want to reopen [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7833/networking)

Comment: A device like this is not commonly used in professional business networks. It is very common in SOHO gear. Almost any two pieces of network gear to be combined into a single package, and is very common in various situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite common to find a router with a switch-module (plus a bridge to wlan) in a single device.